# ActionListener doesn't trigger event

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

When i run this i get the debug message "Listener has been made" so their has been an inner class AddSpectrumGraphListener object made.
But the actionlistener won't respond to a click on the button.

Does someone see the mistake i made?

My controller class:

```
public class Controller {

    private Model model;
    private MainFrame mainFrame;

    public Controller(Model model, MainFrame view){
        this.model = model;
        this.mainFrame = view;

        mainFrame.getLeftBar().getSpecPanel()
                .addCreateSpectrumGraphButtonListener(new AddSpectrumGraphListener());    
    }

    public class AddSpectrumGraphListener implements ActionListener {

        public AddSpectrumGraphListener(){
            super();
            System.out.println("Listener has been made");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println(" triggerd");      

        }
    }
}
```

the JPanel class with the button:

```
public class SpectrumEditPanel extends JPanel{

    private JButton createGraphBttn;

    public SpectrumEditPanel (){
        super(new GridLayout(0,1));

        // Button
        createGraphBttn = new JButton("Maak Grafiekie");
        add(createGraphBttn);

    }

    public void addCreateSpectrumGraphButtonListener(ActionListener al) {
        createGraphBttn.addActionListener(al);
    } 
}
```

I've added the complete code here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y03dal7qn4rwqqo/TFVsimulation.zip

thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you looking to dynamically create a button?

Comment: The way you are going about adding your listener seems a bit perplexing to me, would be simpler IMO to just make the controller or panel class be the listener, but I don't actually see a problem. You are making one and adding it. So curious I guess. This code might not be the where the problem is. Maybe look around and see if the MainFrame reference you are passing in to the Controller constructor is stale somehow. In other words, maybe you've overwritten it or the button somewhere by accident or something like that.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: the more common way to add an action listener is to write the listener as an anonymous inner class. but to me your code looks correct. If I were you, I would debug to see whether mainFrame.getLeftBar().getSpecPanel() returns the same panel that you see and clicked the button. Hope that help.

Comment: I've added the complete code